# Output file creation error with pentaho and task schedule windows

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, windows-task-scheduler

I have configured a machine with windows server 2016 and pentaho CE 7.0
I have already developed several Jobs and Transformations with their respective .BAT.
My problem occurs when I run the Jobs from the Windows Task Scheduler, which indicates the following error in the log:

> Error opening new file 2020/07/08 13:43:36 - Microsoft Excel Writer.0
>
> - ERROR (version 7.0.0.0-25, build 1 from 2016-11-05 15.35.36 by buildguy) : java.io.IOException: Error creating output file! Parent
>   directory [file:///W:/Prueba] does not exist.

I already confirmed that the route exists and the most frustrating thing is that if I run the .BAT with a double click I get to the route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for permissions ! it seems probably your script dont have correct permission to write in that folder.